# How to Pass Parameters to JS HTTP Adapters in MobileFirst 8

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Adapter JS

```
function getCitiesByCountry(countryName)

{ 

 var request =
    var request=
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:GetCitiesByCountry>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:CountryName>INDIA</web:CountryName>
      </web:GetCitiesByCountry>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>;

var input =

 {
    method: 'post',
    returnedContentType: 'xml',
    path: '/globalweather.asmx',
    body: {
        content: request.toString(),
        contentType: 'text/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
};
var result = MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
return result.Envelope.Body;
};
```

Adapter XML

```
<displayName>JavaScriptSOAP</displayName>
<description>JavaScriptSOAP</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>www.webservicex.net</domain>
        <port>80</port>
    </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>

<procedure name="getCitiesByCountry" secured ="false"/>
```

Index.js

```
   function submitRequest()
 {
  var resourceRequest = new             WLResourceRequest("adapters/JavaScriptSOAP/getCitiesByCountry", WLResourceRequest.POST);
  resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "['India']");
  resourceRequest.send().then(
   function(response) {
        alert('response   '+JSON.stringify(response.responseText));
   },
        function(response) {

        alert("HTTP Failure  "+JSON.stringify(response));
     }
    );
    }
```

I need to pass parameters to http Adapters.It contains Country Name.I have included the Country name in Index js file itself.While previewing the app,I receive the error code 415,

And in console I received as

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID test. An invalid user ID or password was specified.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID test. An invalid user ID or password was specified.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID test. An invalid user ID or password was specified.
```

I have:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600
Windows 7

What authentication I have to give .How to overcome the error??

Comment: I can't understand the question. What is the client code that calls this adapter?

Comment: Iam unable to call the adapter from the client code (i.e index.js).Now I have included the index.js code also.

Comment: When exactly do you get this error? You mention - compiling . Compiling what - your application ?

Comment: I got that  response when I click the button Which call the submitRequest function in index.js.

Answer (score 1):

A 415 is "Unsupported media type". This means that the server decided that the request you sent does not contain the type of data that the server thinks it should.

The reason you are getting this is because you are sending a POST request without a body and with query parameters. What you can do to solve this is to change the POST request to a GET request. Just change

```
 WLResourceRequest("adapters/JavaScriptSOAP/getCitiesByCountry", WLResourceRequest.POST);
```

to

```
 WLResourceRequest("adapters/JavaScriptSOAP/getCitiesByCountry", WLResourceRequest.GET);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the arguments incorrectly. `params` is an array therefore your code should look like

```
function submitRequest() { var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("adapters/JavaScriptSOAP/getCitiesByCountry", WLResourceRequest.POST); resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "['India']"); resourceRequest.send().then( function(response) { alert('response '+JSON.stringify(response.responseText)); }, function(response) { alert("HTTP Failure "+JSON.stringify(response)); } ); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add secured="false" to the procedure declaration in the XML file:

```
<procedure name="getCitiesByCountry" secured="false"/>
```

Comment: @shmulik.Still receiving same error.Whether I have to add any Authentication in config.xml file??